# How to generate inter-related args with clojure.spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have a method that removes common prefixes from pairs of strings, and have been trying to create a generator for it.  It is trivial to generate pairs of random strings, but how can I enforce that many of the pairs have common prefixes?  Simply filtering the pairs generates an insufficient number of examples, so I'm trying to create a custom generator to satisfy the requirements.

Here is what I have now; it works, but I'd like to generate better parameters:

```
(ns liblevenshtein.distance
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as spec]
            [clojure.spec.gen.alpha :as gen]))

(spec/def ::word
  (spec/and string? (complement nil?)))

(spec/def ::v-w (spec/cat :v ::word, :w ::word))

(spec/def ::non-empty-v-w
  (spec/and ::v-w (fn [{:keys [v w]}]
                    (and (not-empty v)
                         (not-empty w)))))

(defn- drop-common-prefix [v w]
  (loop [v v, a (.charAt v 0), s (.substring v 1),
        w w, b (.charAt w 0), t (.substring w 1)]
    (if (and (= a b)
            (not-empty s)
            (not-empty t))
      (recur s (.charAt s 0) (.substring s 1)
            t (.charAt t 0) (.substring t 1))
      [v a s, w b t])))

(spec/fdef drop-common-prefix
        :args ::non-empty-v-w
        :ret (spec/tuple string? char? string?, string? char? string?)
        :fn (fn [{{:keys [v w]} :args, [v' a s, w' b t] :ret}]
              (and (= v' (str a s))
                   (.endsWith v v')
                   (= w' (str b t))
                   (.endsWith w w'))))
```

Experimenting with generators, I've come up with the following.  It generates pairs of strings satisfying my requirement, but I do not know how to split them into the arguments for my function:

```
user=> (def prefix-pair-gen (gen/fmap (fn [[u v w]] [(str u v) (str u w)]) (spec/gen (spec/coll-of string? :type vector? :count 3))))
#'user/prefix-pair-gen
user=> (spec/def ::prefix-pair (spec/with-gen (spec/coll-of string? :type vector? :count 2) (fn [] prefix-pair-gen)))
:user/prefix-pair
user=> (gen/sample (spec/gen ::prefix-pair))
(["" ""]
 ["c" "cR"]
 ["lZ" "2F"]
 ["8a" "8a4"]
 ["n1D8CSq" "n1D8Gb1k"]
 ["X4PO" "X4Pu"]
 ["eAVM1" "eAVM1qg"]
 ["5e3DkZ6i" "5e3DkZv4Y"]
 ["3P7210" "3P7245cHM"]
 ["1c4D2j4UUK738" "1c4D2joFjd"])
```

Comment: is your question, Given a sequence of pairs, how to call a two-argument function using each pair in the sequence for the arguments?

Comment: No, but it is related.  I need to generate tuples of related arguments for spec'ing functions: https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_spec_ing_functions

Comment: It is possible that this is beyond the scope of clojure.spec, in which case I'll move the generator logic to unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, and it is trivial. I should have paid more attention to the docs.  The `:args` [documentation for `fdef`](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/fdef) states:

> :args A regex spec for the function arguments as they were a list to
>   be passed to apply - in this way, a single spec can handle functions
>   with multiple arities

As such, I can provide the generated vectors directly, as follows:

```
(defn- drop-common-prefix [v w]
  (loop [v v, a (.charAt v 0), s (.substring v 1),
         w w, b (.charAt w 0), t (.substring w 1)]
    (if (and (= a b)
             (not-empty s)
             (not-empty t))
      (recur s (.charAt s 0) (.substring s 1)
             t (.charAt t 0) (.substring t 1))
      [v a s, w b t])))

(def prefix-pair-gen
  (gen/fmap
   (fn [[u v w]]
     [(str u v) (str u w)])
   (spec/gen
    (spec/and (spec/coll-of string? :type vector? :count 3)
              (fn [[u v w]]
                (and (not-empty v)
                     (not-empty w)))))))

(spec/def ::prefix-pair
  (spec/with-gen
    (spec/coll-of string? :type vector? :count 2)
    (constantly prefix-pair-gen)))

(spec/fdef drop-common-prefix
           :args ::prefix-pair
           :ret (spec/tuple string? char? string?, string? char? string?)
           :fn (fn [{[v w] :args, [v' a s, w' b t] :ret}]
                 (and (= v' (str a s))
                      (.endsWith v v')
                      (= w' (str b t))
                      (.endsWith w w'))))
```

I can verify its correctness via:

```
user> (stest/summarize-results (stest/check `liblevenshtein.distance/drop-common-prefix))
{:sym liblevenshtein.distance/drop-common-prefix}
{:total 1, :check-passed 1}
```